# Обработка HTML-формы в рамках одного скрипта: как удалить форму после отправки данных?

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
  $client = clear($_GET['id']);
  $query = queryMysql("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE id='$client'");
  $b = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
  ?>
  <form method="post">
    <div style="text-align: center">
      <div style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
        Действительно хотите удалить контакт
        <?php if(!empty($b['name'])) echo "<strong> ".$b['name']."</strong>" ?>?
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" name="del" />
      <input type="submit" class="accept" value="Да" />
    </div>
  </form>
  <?php
}

if(isset($_POST['del'])) {
  $query = queryMysql("DELETE FROM clients WHERE id='$client'");
  echo '<div class="success">Контакт успешно удален</div>';
}
?>
```

Идея такова. При нажатии на кнопку "удалить" нас перекидывает на страницу с кодом выше. Там спрашивается, точно ли я хочу удалить контакт? Если я жму "ДА", то показывается сообщение, что контакт удален. Но возникла проблема, что после нажатия "ДА" окошко то появляется (так и надо), а вот вопрос не убирается. Вроде поставил `empty($_POST['del'])` но что то не катит.

Comment: Не совсем разобрался, но, к сведению, параметр может быть `isset`, но `empty` одновременно.

Comment: Проблема в том, что сообщение "Контакт успешно удален" появляется под надписью "Действительно хотите удалить контакт?" а не заменяет ее

Comment: Замените проверку empty($del) на (!isset($del))

Comment: if(isset($_GET['id']) && !isset($del)) {... Так не помогает

Comment: а нет. Вот если так пишу: if(isset($_GET['id']) && !isset($_POST['del'])) {... то окошко высвечивается как надо, а вот контакт не удаляется из БД

Comment: Ну так потому что ` $client = clear($_GET['id']);` надо в таком случае во второй блок перенести.

Comment: Да ну потому, что так не делают.

У вас есть две отдельные логические ситуации когда нужно вывести сообщение "Удалить?" и когда собственно уже.

Условие первое -  isset($_GET['id'])

Условие второе (ОТДЕЛЬНЫЙ вложенный в первое блок IF) empty($_GET['del']) который в одном случае пишет форму, а во втором - сообщение об упешном удалении (причем желательно проверять успешность выполнения запроса). ВСЕ.

Answer (score 1):

Вам лучше вынести обработчик формы, до самой формы, если массив `$_POST` пуст - выведется только форма. Если он заполнен, то в обработчике вы сможете прервать работу скрипта при помощи `exit()` (с возможным последующим редиректом).

```
<?php
// Обработчик предшествует форме
if(isset($_POST['del'])) {
    $query = queryMysql("DELETE FROM clients WHERE id='$client'");
    echo '<div class="success">Контакт успешно удален</div>';
    // Останавливаем работу скрипта, при необходимости
    // осуществляем редирект
    exit();
}


if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
  $client = clear($_GET['id']);
  $query = queryMysql("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE id='$client'");
  $b = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
  ?>
  <form method="post">
    <div style="text-align: center">
      <div style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
        Действительно хотите удалить контакт
        <?php if(!empty($b['name'])) echo "<strong> ".$b['name']."</strong>" ?>?
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" name="del" />
      <input type="submit" class="accept" value="Да" />
    </div>
  </form>
  <?php
}
?>
```

При таком подходе вам не потребуется усложнять условия вывода формы.